# No module named error. How to import function from .pyx file in python from different directories rooted to same directory?

Tags: python, python-3.x, cython, importerror, pyx

I am running code from main.py. Following is my directory structure:

I'm using Python 3.6 and Linux.

```
PackA
     PackB
          PackC
               _main.py
          PackD 
               cython_file.pyx
                         def func()   # function defined here. 
               cython_file.pxd
               __init__.py   
                     func()           # function call.
```

The Package pyximport is installed used by Cython.

I'm importing the cython file in `__init__.py` using:

```
from cython_file import func
```

Error: ImportError: cannot import name 'func'

Where am I doing wrong?

Comment: In the absence of other evidence I'd suggest that `cython_file` doesn't have an importable Python object called `func`.

Comment: I agree with @DavidW, this question needs a [mcve], otherwise nobody would be able to help.

Comment: I'm also wondering if it needs relative imports (i.e. `from .cython_file import func`). I can never remember what's actually required though

Comment: @DavidW
I tried out relative imports suggested here but it is showing the error ```ModuelNotFoundError: No module named PartD.cython_file```

I have used 
```import sys
sys.path.append("..") ``` 
in ```_main.py```.

Comment: Instead of creating a function ```func``` in cython_file, if I create in another python file, the
code works fine.

Comment: This really needs to be a complete example. You say you've used pyximport - we don't know where. You show one line of the pyx file and none of the pxd.  There could be stuff in that affects it.

Comment: I was not using pyximport initially. Now when I used:
```
import pyximport 
pyximport.install()
```
now it is showing 
ImportError: Building module PackD.cython_file failed: ["distutils.errors.CompileError: command 'C:\\\\Program Files (x86)\\\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\\\2019\\\\Community\\\\VC\\\\Tools\\\\MSVC\\\\14.24.28314\\\\bin\\\\HostX86\\\\x64\\\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2\n"]

Comment: pyximport can hide some problems as well. You could start by compiling the cython file by hand and importing it by hand in a python terminal from the same directory: type `python` to start python, then in the python console `from cython_file import func`.